# Amazon SES need to have a smtp server running for receive emails?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, smtp, amazon-ses

I've read the Amazon's documentations about SES hundred times and the only thing I really didn't understand yet is if I need to have an smtp server like Aws Work Email or other to receiving email on SES and execute a lambda function, cause I don't have any service of this kind running except SES.

When I try to save the email in a S3 bucket it stores only a file with the name: "AMAZON_SES_SETUP_NOTIFICATION" and the contents:

> Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2016 21:19:29 +0000 To: recipient@example.com From:
>   Amazon Web Services  Subject: Amazon SES
>   Setup Notification
>
> Hello,
>
> You received this message because you attempted to set up Amazon SES
>   to deliver emails to this S3 bucket.
>
> Please note that the rule that you configured to deliver emails to
>   this S3 bucket is only valid if the entire setup process is
>   successful. For more information about setting up email-receiving
>   rules, see the Amazon SES Developer Guide at
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html .
>
> Thank you for using Amazon SES!
>
> The Amazon SES Team

So I would to know if is need tha I had som smtp server to get it working, and if no what can I missing to SES generate that message, sory for my english it is not my main language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SES is primarily for outgoing emails, and they have recently added the ability to receive emails and save the contents to an S3 bucket - none of that requires a separate server to be running.

And while having SES receive emails and save them to an S3 bucket is possibly incredibly useful - depending on your use case - its not really a replacement for a traditional email server.

If you need traditional email services, and would like to host them on AWS, Workmail is the best option.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to send the content of the emails that arrive for a support wss chat server through a lambda function, do you know why it is storing only the notification in the s3 ?